# Jquery select option value and add a numeric value and show result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have the postage option once selected add the subtotal to it, then populate a div /  tag
I've tried this bit of jquery code, altered it to my id's but no luck.
Where am I going wrong?

```js
$('#shipping').on('select', function() {
  var shipping = parseFloat($('#shipping').attr("price")) || 0;
  $('#amount').val(shipping + {{$subtotal}});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
  <div class="cart_total_title">Subtotal</div>
  <div class="cart_total_value ml-auto" id="total">£{{$subtotal}}</div>
</li>
<li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
  <div class="cart_total_title">Shipping</div>
  <span></span>
  <select name="shipping" id="shipping" class="" style="width:auto;margin-left:150px;" require="required">
    <option value="" price="4.99">Royal Mail UK Next day delivery: £4.99</option>
    <option value="" price="3.99">Royal Mail Standard delivery: £3.99</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. I presume the `{{$subtotal}}` string is being replaced by a server-side library?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is retrieving the value of the "shipping" select. So:

```
var shipping = parseFloat($('#shipping').attr("price")) || 0;
```

should be

```
var shipping = parseFloat($('#shipping').val()) || 0;
```

And the value of your options should not be empty, you should set arbitrary values (let's say `UK_NEXT_DAY` and `STANDARD_DELIVERY`):

```
<option value="UK_NEXT_DAY" price="4.99">Royal Mail UK Next day delivery: £4.99</option>
<option value="STANDARD_DELIVERY" price="3.99">Royal Mail Standard delivery: £3.99</option>
```

But you could as well have the values populated with the price, but this is a bad practice in my view regarding the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

```
<option value="4.99" price="4.99">Royal Mail UK Next day delivery: £4.99</option>
<option value="3.99" price="3.99">Royal Mail Standard delivery: £3.99</option>
```

Comment: I tried this, however the #amount input is not being populated :/

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working, you can check with try to console value on dropdown change. i have already console the selected value and its working. Solution is something like `$('option:selected', this).attr("price")`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','select#shipping', function() {
        var shipping = parseFloat($('option:selected', this).attr("price"));
        console.log(shipping);
        $('#amount').val(shipping);
    });
    });
</script>
<li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
  <div class="cart_total_title">Subtotal</div>
  <div class="cart_total_value ml-auto" id="total">£{{$subtotal}}</div>
</li>
<li class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
  <div class="cart_total_title">Shipping</div>
  <span></span>
  <select name="shipping" id="shipping" class="shipping" style="width:auto;margin-left:150px;" require="required">
    <option value="4.99" price="4.99">Royal Mail UK Next day delivery: £4.99</option>
    <option value="3.99" price="3.99">Royal Mail Standard delivery: £3.99</option>
  </select>
</li>
```